# How do the arguments and ternary operator work when retrieving data from a db table?

Tags: c, sqlite, loops, for-loop, c-strings

The program is about retrieving the entire table from a database in sqlite using c.

DB table

```
"1" "Audi"  "52642"
"2" "Mercedes"  "57127"
"3" "Skoda" "9000"
"4" "Volvo" "29000"
"5" "Bentley"   "350000"
"6" "Citroen"   "21000"
"7" "Hummer"    "41400"
"8" "Volkswagen"    "21600"
```

Program

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int callback(void *, int, char **, char **);


int main(void) {
    
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    
    int rc = sqlite3_open("db1.db", &db);
    
    char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars";
        
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);
    
    
    sqlite3_close(db);
    
    return 0;
}

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, 
                    char **azColName) {
    
    NotUsed = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

        printf("%s b", argv[i]?argv[i]:"NULL");
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The operation in question

```
printf("%s b", argv[i]?argv[i]:"NULL");
```

I get that the rows of a table are passed as arguments. But what separates each of the field in a row? And how is ternary operator able to separate the fields?

Output

```
1 bAudi b52642 b
2 bMercedes b57127 b
3 bSkoda b9000 b
4 bVolvo b29000 b
5 bBentley b350000 b
6 bCitroen b21000 b
7 bHummer b41400 b
8 bVolkswagen b21600 b
```

Comment: The ternary operator does not separate fields. It just outputs either the string stored in argv[i] or the string literal "NULL".

Comment: It seems each string argv[i] contains a field.

Comment: But when I write ```printf("%s", argv[i]);``` I get o/p ```1Audi52642```. How does it iterate over the element?

Comment: No, you get `"1 b"`, `"Audi b"` and `"52642 b"` in your callback

Comment: You seem to misinterpret how the callback works. Your function is called for each line of the table and each field is passed in an element of the array.

Comment: Yes. callback is invoked for each row. Thank you.

Comment: That line is pretty self-explanatory... if you understand what `if(pointer)` does, you should be able to figure out the `?:` line as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the output as for example of this line

```
1 bAudi b52642 b
```

and the loop in the function `callback`

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

    printf("%s b", argv[i]?argv[i]:"NULL");
}

printf("\n");
```

it seems that each string `argv[i]` if it is not equal to `NULL` points to a field outputted in lines. For example for the first line the pointed string `argv[0]` contains `"1"`, `argv[1]` contains `"Audi"` and `argv[2]` contains `"52642"`.`

So imagine that `argc` is equal to `3`  and `argv` is a dynamically (or automatically) allocated array of pointers to strings like for example

```
{ "1", "Audi", "52642" }
```

So this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

    printf("%s b", argv[i]?argv[i]:"NULL");
}

printf("\n");
```

will output the line

```
1 bAydi b52642 b
```

Here is a demonstrative program that uses your function `callback`.  I only commented unused parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int callback( /*void *NotUsed,*/ int argc, char **argv /*, char **azColName*/ ) {
    
//    NotUsed = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

        printf("%s b", argv[i]?argv[i]:"NULL");
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { argc = 3 };
    char *argv[argc] =
    {
        "1", "Audi", "52642"
    };
    
    callback( argc, argv );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 bAudi b52642 b
```

So the function `callback` accepts an array of pointers to fields in each read record.

Comment: No. argv[0] is 1Audi52642. argv[1] is 2Mercedes57127. argv is a 2D array, but when i do argv[i][0], i get int values which possibly are pointer values.

Comment: @KenGraham You are wrong. Within the function callback you have an array of pointers to strings argv. This array is traversed in the for loop.

Comment: @KenGraham your code sample and output clearly show that `argv[0]` only holds `"1"`

Comment: Yes. My bad. I would have made a mistake somewhere while learning it.